# android: “id cannot be resolved or is not a field” error?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, widget

hey i keep getting this ERR "widgetContext cannot be resolved or is not a field"
can some one please help me out to figure this out?

```
public class widgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider 
{
    public static Vector<widgetProvider> widgetProvider = new Vector<widgetProvider>();
    public static Vector<Context> widgetContext = new Vector<Context>();
    public static Vector<AppWidgetManager> widgetManager =new Vector<AppWidgetManager>();
    public static Vector<int[]> widgetId= new Vector<int[]>();
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {   
        if(context != null){
            widgetHomePage(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        }       

        for (int i=0; i< widgetProvider.size() ; i++)
        {
            context = widgetProvider.widgetContext.elementAt(i);
            appWidgetManager = widgetProvider.widgetManager.elementAt(i);
            appWidgetIds = widgetProvider.widgetId.elementAt(i);

            RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);
            setTextView(rv);
            openMainActivity(context, rv);
            updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds, rv);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `widgetProvider` and `widgetContext` are 2 separate variables, so you cannot string them together like you've done here:

```
context = widgetProvider.widgetContext.elementAt(i);
```

Anything after the `.` must belong to that instance of `widgetProvider`